# Access to the parent key prop for all childrens events

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that generate multiple row , inside those rows i have many input that i bound an `onChange` function.
I need to access to the key of the current row for `setState` purpose. So i declare a data attribute for all my inputs `data-id={key}` ,

all this work perfectly but i think this is a high cost ressource that might be avoided ?

I was used to pass the key prop to the common parent (`<tr>`) here in Jquery and use the function `parentsUntil()`. but i don't think this is the goal here in React. Any suggestion how to avoid passing the key for all my inputs and access to the current key props on my parent (`<tr>`) ?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you're trying to do? Why are you using data-id and why do you need to find the parent?

Comment: I would like to avoid passing the key prop to all  the childrens just to make the code less populated and maybe for better perfomance ?

Answer (score 1):

Real DOM elements/attributes can be `reached` in event handlers, by sth like:

```
handleChange(event) {
  const parentRow = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;  // input -> td -> tr
  const id = parentRow.attr("data-id");
  this.props.handleChange( {
    value: event.target.value, 
    rowId: id
  });
}
```

Of course, handler can (and should) be entirely defined (and binded) in parent and passed as prop.

Answer (score 1):

If looking at your code (which was embedded to question)

```
<tr key={key} id={key}>
    <td>
        <input name="quoteProducts.code" data-id={key} value={code} onChange={this._handleChange}/>
    </td>
```

There is `this._handleChange` handler. When it will be called, first argument will be [`event`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp). It has [`currentTarget`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp) property which is [`DOM Element`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp). DOM Element has [`parentNode`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) property. In your code parentNode will be `<td>`. It in turn has also parentNode which will be `<tr>` you need. And you can access ll properties of `<tr>` you need.

Example:

```
_handleChange (event) {
    event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.id // This is id of <tr>
}
```

`id` of any React component is easily accessible using previous example.